Formal definition of function
In set theory, functions are usually defined as subsets of a Cartesian product. However, this way, the functions $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and $g\colon\Bbb R\to[-1,1]$, defined as $f(x)=g(x)=\sin x$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$, should be equal. However, I think $f$ and $g$ are still distinct objects, even though the values are the same. Am I wrong? Is there some distinction to be made, or $f=g$? If it's the case that the latter is true, then there is no way of assigning a codomain to a function in a unique way, thus the notation $\operatorname{Cod}(f)$ would be pretty much an informal one.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Formal_definition

The most formal definition of function which I have encountered so far is given in the Italian book "Analisi Uno" by Giuseppe De Marco: it fully addresses your issue. He writes:

Let $X, Y$ be sets. A function (or application, or map) from $X$ to $Y$ is an ordered triple $(X, Y, G)$, where $G \subseteq X\times Y$, such that: $$\forall x, x \in X \implies \exists! y \in Y: (x, y) \in G. $$
$G$ is called the $graph$ of the function.


Thank you. I have heard of De Marco's textbook, but never actually read it. I used Marcellini-Sbordone as my first textbook and Baby Rudin for a second read.

De Marco's book is not easy. I wouldn't recommend it to a beginner in Real Analysis. However, for me it is an excellent read for a second-year undergraduate student who has learnt the basic concepts of (Euclidean) topology and has learnt enough in their first course in analysis. Marcellni-Sbordone is a classic to start: I have used it too for my first course in Analysis.

By the way, recently I came across an even tougher book, which is  "Basic Real Analysis" by Houshang H. Sohrab :). It also covers some topics which are usually taught later, like pointwise/uniform convergence, Lebesgue integration and a really interesting appendix on the construction of real numbers

Yeah, Baby Rudin does cover those topics. Marcellini and Sbordone explain them in Analisi Due, if I remember correctly. I have never heard of Sohrab's book, I'll take a look, thanks.
